Simple divisibility question
I want to find all $k$ such that for every pair of positive integers $(m, n)$, $(km + n)  \mid{} (kn + m) \implies m \mid{} n$.
Here are my ideas so far:
Say that $(km + n) \mid{} (kn + m)$. Then there exists some integer $q$ where $kn + m = q(km + n)$. I then added $km + n$ to both sides, which gave me the equation $kn + m + km + m = (q + 1)(km + n)$, which allowed me to factor the left side and end up with
$$(m + n)(k + 1) = (q + 1)(km + n)$$
That is, we have $(km + n) \mid{} (m + n)(k + 1)$. However, expanding this out further (it implies there exists some $q_2$ such that $q_2(km + n) = (m + n)(k + 1)$), I don't see a way to reach the conclusion that $m \mid{} n$.
Can anyone provide some hints or a solution to this question?
